# Django-Tables2 LinkColumn link goes to wrong item

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a Django project and I am having issues with the hyperlink (LinkColumn from Django-tables2) going to the incorrect entry and I cannot figure out why it is occurring or how to fix it.

Very specifically, I can go to the admin view and create a publication. When it comes to setting the author (a.k.a. pi) or sample, there is a drop down menu for foreign key fields (sample/pi) that shows all existing entries from which I can choose one. When I choose a sample and pi then look at the table rendering, the hyperlink is there for the sample, pi, and the publication title. The publication title correctly takes me to the publication_detail page. The hyperlink for the sample will take me to a sample detail page, but it is not the same sample I selected from the admin page. I have the same issue for the author; it takes me to the detail view page of AN author, just not the one I selected from the admin page.

I use django-tables2 several times throughout the project and like how the tables are rendered, but cannot figure out how to address this problem. I have included *some* of my code (please note I included a bit of the PI and Sample model, but not all of it).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

`models.py`

```
class PI(models.Model): #this is a smattering of the PI model
   l_name = models.CharField('L Name', blank=False, max_length=100, default='')
   f_name = models.CharField('F Name', blank=False, max_length=100, default='')
   m_name = models.CharField('MI', null=True, blank=True, max_length=1, default='' )
   phone = PhoneField(blank=True, default='')
   email = models.EmailField('Email', blank=True, max_length=100, default='')

class Sample(models.Model): #this is a smattering of the Sample model
   sample_name = models.CharField('Sample', max_length=16)
   pi = models.ForeignKey(PI, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   submitter = models.ForeignKey('Submitter', blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Publication(models.Model):
   sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(PI, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   title_p = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
   volume = models.IntegerField('Volume', blank=True, null=True)
   number = models.IntegerField('Number', blank=True, null=True)
   pages = models.CharField('Pages', default='', max_length=20, blank=True)
   year = models.IntegerField('Year', blank=True, null=True)
   doi = models.CharField('DOI', default='', max_length=30, blank=False)
   journal = models.CharField('Journal', default='', max_length=100, blank=False)
   abstract = models.CharField('Abstract', default='', max_length=1000, blank=False)
   issn = models.CharField('ISSN', default='', max_length=10, blank=False)
   url = models.CharField('URL', default='', max_length=100, blank=False)
   eprint = models.CharField('Eprint', default='', max_length=100, blank=False)

   class Meta:
      ordering = ('sample', 'author', 'title_p', 'journal', 'volume', 'number', 'pages', 'year', 'doi', 'abstract', 'issn', 'url', 'eprint')

   def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('publication-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

   def __str__(self):
      return f'{self.sample}, {self.author}, {self.title_p}, {self.volume}, {self.number}, {self.pages}, {self.year}, {self.doi}, {self.journal}, {self.abstract}, {self.issn}, {self.url}, {self.eprint}'
```

`tables.py`

```
class PublicationTable(tables.Table):
   sample = tables.LinkColumn('sample-detail', args=[A('pk')])
   author = tables.LinkColumn('pi-detail', args=[A('pk')])
   title_p = tables.LinkColumn('publication-detail', args=[A('pk')])

   class Meta:
      model = Publication
      fields = ( 'sample', 'author', 'title_p', 'journal', 'year', )
      exclude = ( 'volume', 'number', 'pages', 'doi', 'abstract', 'issn', 'url', 'eprint', )
      list_display = ('sample', 'author', 'title_p', 'year', 'journal', )
```

`views.py`

```
class PublicationListView(generic.ListView):
   model = Publication
   paginate_by = 100

@login_required
def publication_view(request, pk):
   publication = Publication.objects.get(pk = pk)
   table = PublicationTable(Publication.objects.filter(publication=pk))
   RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
   return render(request, 'samples/publication_detail.html', {'publication': publication, 'publication-detail': table}) 

@login_required
def publication_table(request):
   table = PublicationTable(Publication.objects.all())
   RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
   return render(request, 'samples/publication_list.html', {'publication_table': table}) 

class PublicationDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Publication
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [ 
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('samples/', views.sam, name='sam'),
   path('sample/<int:pk>', views.SampleDetailView.as_view(), name='sample-detail'),
   path('pi/', views.pi_table, name='pi_table'),
   path('pi/<int:pk>', views.pi_view, name='pi-detail'),
   path('publication/', views.publication_table, name='publication_table'),
   path('publication/<int:pk>', views.PublicationDetailView.as_view(), name='publication-detail'),
]
```

A bit of code from `samples/templates/samples/publication_list.py`

`{% render_table publication_table %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, passing `pk` through accessor means, it will pass the primary key of Publication Model objects for `pi-details`, `sample-details`, and so on. So you need to change it so that you pass the respective primary keys throught the accessor like this:

```
class PublicationTable(tables.Table):
   sample = tables.LinkColumn('sample-detail', args=[A('sample_id')])
   author = tables.LinkColumn('pi-detail', args=[A('author_id')])
   title_p = tables.LinkColumn('publication-detail', args=[A('pk')])
```

Comment: Thank you @ruddra for the explanation, that solved the problem.

Comment: Or define a `get_absolute_url()`-method on all your models and use linkcolumn without arguments (or `tables.Column(linkify=True)`